# ajax code not taking the data from table to second row

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

hi guys i have an issue on ajax. where ajax can't work  to take the data of second rows.

### This's code in model

```
 function getdtbarang($barcode = FALSE) {
         if ($barcode === FALSE)
        {
                $query = $this->db1->get('tblmstbarang');
                return $query->result_array();
        }

        $query = $this->db1->get_where('tblmstbarang', array('barcode' => $barcode));
        return $query->row_array();
        }
```

### This's code in controller:

```
 function getdatabarang() {
        $barcode = $this->input->post('barcode');
        $data=$this->Mbarang->getdtbarang($barcode);
        echo json_encode($data);
        }
```

### This's ajax code in view. NB:some code has updated

```
     <script type="text/javascript">

   function getdatabrg(barcode){
    $('#barcode_2').each(function() {    
        var barcode =$('#barcode_2').val();   
       $.ajax({
            type    : "post",
            data    : "barcode=" +barcode,                       
            url     : "<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/master/barang/Cbarang/getdatabarang",
            dataType:"json",
            success: function(data){ 
            for(var i in data)
              {
            var obj= data[i];          


                $("#barang_nama_2").val(obj.barang_nama);
                $("#harga_beli_2").val(obj.harga_beli);

          }}

        }); 


    });
}


    $(document).ready(function() { 
     $('#barcode_2').keyup(function() {
      getdatabrg(); 
    });
  });
      </script>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="barcode"    name="barcode[]"     value="<?php echo set_value('barcode['.$i.']') ;?>" onKeyUp="getValues()" ></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="barang_nama" name="barang_nama[]" value="<?php echo set_value('barang_nama['.$i.']') ;?>" onKeyUp="getValues()"  disabled></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="harga_beli"  name="harga_beli[]"  value="<?php echo set_value('harga_beli['.$i.']');?>" onKeyUp="getValues()" disabled></td>

    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="barcode_2"        name="barcode[]"     value="<?php $a=set_value('barcode[0]') ; echo $a;?>"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="barang_nama_2"    name="barang_nama[]" value="<?php $a=set_value('barang_nama[0]') ; echo $a;?>" onKeyUp="getValues()" readonly></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="harga_beli_2"     name="harga_beli[]"  value="<?php $a=set_value('harga_beli[0]'); echo $a;?>" onKeyUp="getValues()"  readonly></td>

    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="barcode_3"      name="barcode[]"     value="<?php echo $detail->barcode;?>"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="barang_nama_3"  name="barang_nama[]" value="<?php echo $detail->barang_nama;?>" onKeyUp="getValues()" readonly></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="harga_beli_3"   name="harga_beli[]"  value="<?php echo $detail->harga_beli;?>"  onKeyUp="getValues()" readonly></td>
```

i hope getting solve for this problem. many thanks for all your response.

Comment: Please show output from getdata_barang(

Comment: You cannot use the same id for html elements. jQuery will only fetch the first element.

Comment: @ mplungjan https://i.stack.imgur.com/6wA7z.png

Comment: @ mplungjan this ouput version of text if i to run on url://.. index.php/master/barang/Cbarang/getdata_barang
{"barang_nama":"","harga_beli":""}

Comment: `url     :"<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/master/barang/Cbarang/getdata_barang",` this line is like eg, `abc.comindex.php/master/barang/Cbarang/getdata_barang` If I'm not wrong. You can umm add `/` `url     :"<?php echo base_url()."/";?>index.php/master/barang/Cbarang/getdata_barang",`

Comment: You are not returning anything from model

Answer (score 1):

Like Zerfiryn mentioned : "You cannot use the same id for html elements. jQuery will only fetch the first element"

solutions:  you can use the same class multiple times on html elements. Call not the id in your ajax but the class `form-control`.
So, replace `$("#barcode")` with `$(".form-control")`

writing an answer cause I can't place comments -.-

Answer (score 0):

You have not constructed model correctly your model is directly outputting the data which so you will end up with the output something like

```
[{barang_name:"value"},{harga_beli:"value"}][{barang_name:"value"},{harga_beli:"value"}][{barang_name:"value"},{harga_beli:"value"}]...
```

which is not correct JSON
your should output correct JSON your output should be
[  [{barang_name:"value"},{harga_beli:"value"}], [{barang_name:"value"},{harga_beli:"value"}],.. ]
which is **array of arrays**

The simplest way to achieve this is

1 ) get the desired data from your model

```
function your_model_function()
{
   $result = execute_query($sql);
   $rows = array();
   if($result->num_rows)
   {
     while($row = $result->fetch_row())
     $rows[] = $row;
   }
   return $rows;
}
```

2) use json_encode to  encode your whole data array in json format

```
 $data = $this->model->your_model_func();
 echo json_encode($data);
```

3) Use the JSON in your success callback function

```
 //writing success function of ajax
     function(data)
    {
      for(var i in data)
      {
         var row = data[i];
         // to acccesss the data of row ie json object you can use . operator
         console.log(row.key)
         // manipulate dom content.
      }
    }
```

**NOTE: i have written a pseudo code only you cannot directly copy paste it to get result it's just to clear your mind.**

Comment: please update your Post with updated code @crazycoder

Comment: until today i haven't found yet. please help me buddy.

Comment: this's a message from console if to input a keyword on 1st rows :Object {0: Object, barcode: "8997", barang_nama: "OBH2", harga_beli: "20000"} and else doesn't response

Comment: $data[] = $data;  why you are storing data in data again use different variable and show the ajax response you received

Comment: code is updated. currently is can directly to read the data from controller. i used new code instead of old code. it still not working to call the next data from second row.

Comment: function(data)
    {
      for(var i in data)
      {
         var row = data[i];
         
         console.log(row.key)
        
      }
    }
this code has added in my view but it still not yet.

Comment: right now your code is echoing only one json object and at javascript expecting json array.